# Error when accessing webservice

Tags: web-services

I am trying to access a webservice from vb.net web app. Its throwing error like

"This is a secure webservice and should be accessed through https"

what does this error means? Any solution?

Thanks in Advance,
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

I assume where you are trying to connect to the web service you are trying to connect to something like

http://webservice.services.com

you should be using

https://webservice.services.com